# How to completely remove Clean Master?

Tags: root-access, uninstallation

I am having some troubles with my android phone. It's a Nexus 5 running CyanogenMod 11.

I once installed Clean Master from the Google Play Store and decided (non long after) to uninstall it.

The problem I have is that CleanMaster seems to be still installed as I can sometimes see some popups claiming that "CM Game Booster" could free some RAM/space whatever or even that my android phone is too hot (which is wrong).

I used the app '/system/app mover' from F-DROID to see if something was installed but I couldn't find anything (from user and system apps) related to Clean Master.

The problem is I gave CleanMaster root access (for '15 minutes') when I installed it.

How can I uninstall CleanMaster ?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

The strangest thing is that CleanMaster was installed 3 months ago, uninstalled 1 week later and I only noticed those popups last week. As the popups doesn't disappear untill I quit it (or press clean.. which I don't do) I'm quite sure the problem was not here before last week and nothing was installed last week or the week before..

Comment: It is possible that CleanMaster installed an app, when you allowed root access to it. Search for apps and sort for installation date, then search for suspicious apps and uninstall them.

Comment: I know but there really is nothing that seems to be suspicious :/

Comment: Have you looked at system applications? There is usually no install date but looking at the last modification time of the related files in `/system/app` and `/system/priv-app` should give you more information.

Comment: As said in the post I used an app from F-DROID to investigate in user and system apps. Nothing relevant found but to be honest I don't know a lot about all those system apps which names are often not meaningful to me

Comment: Could you provide the download link to Clean Master that you downloaded and uninstalled? (there are some apps that have similar name, and I wanted to experiment with it)

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cleanmaster.mguard

Comment: Have you cleaned ***dalvik-cache*** since then? Sometimes things will remain, they don't get cleanly uninstalled. Did you also remove the entry for CleanMaster from the Superuser app? Can you please provide a screenshot of the popups? Also you don't mention where and when the popups occur (what apps are being used and your activity).

Comment: @FromBabylon Can you find **`cleanmaster`** with **`Titanium Backup`**?

Comment: @jonvon73 if you're the same user as FromBabylon, I suggest you to request for [account merging](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: I'm not jonvon73.
I didn't clean dalvik-cache after uninstalling CleanMaster. I did remove it from superuser
I won't be able to provide any screenshot as I've erased all data of the phone. Thanks for your help